# Refer template url like ng-include in angular4 and above

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am wondering is there a simple way in angular 4 and above to use templates url in template like we do in ng-include.

scenario:
I am aware of component architecture, but in one of my component i have 400 lines of template and want to move that into chunks and like **a.html**, **b.html** and refer it in my **component.html** as

```
<template *ngTemplateOutlet="a html templateUrl here"></template>
<template *ngTemplateOutlet="b html templateUrl here"></template>
```

If i use component then i need to pass objects to child (as component acts as child) 
i want to reduce my code and not interested in child components, kind of template directives with scope false in angularJS.

Comment: No, angular doesn't let you do this because what you're proposing is a bad idea. It leads to impossible to understand and maintain code and components.  The reason you need to pass inputs to children is because the whole idea is to not have mysterious hidden dependencies on external components in your code as was often the case in angularJS.  This situation is why they got rid of it, because people abused it and then blamed the framework for bad code practice.  If you have a "deep nesting" problem, which is a valid issue, then use a shared service to pass information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, what you can do, if you really don't want to create child components, is instead of using a `templateUrl`, to use a `template` and import `html` strings:

**./templates/templateA.ts**

```
export const templateA: string = `
   <div>templateA</div>
`;
```

**./templates/templateB.ts**

```
export const templateB: string = `
   <div>templateB</div>
`;
```

**./templates/templateC.ts**

```
export const templateC: string = `
   <div>templateC</div>
`;
```

**./templates/index.ts**

```
export {templateA} from './templateA';
export {templateB} from './templateB';
export {templateC} from './templateC';
```

**actual component**

```
import {templateA, templateB, templateC} from './templates';

@Component({
   template: `
     ${templateA}
     ${templateB}
     ${templateC}
   `
})
```

I would like to emphasise though, that if your component exceeds more than 400 lines of templates, it's really really advisable to chop it into readable and way more maintainable chunks. Where you can add a component provider in the root component